# Navigate to a Default View when Application Loaded using Prism 7 in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, prism-7

I follows samples code provided in https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism-Samples-Wpf/blob/master/17-BasicRegionNavigation

I want to achieve the following result when I run the application (without explicitly clicking Navigate to View A). Does anyone know how to do it?
[image: Desired outcome]

I have tried adding `Navigate("ViewA");` after [this line](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism-Samples-Wpf/blob/dd622ba728fe067f7f40df587d5e5eb3d8464d89/17-BasicRegionNavigation/BasicRegionNavigation/ViewModels/MainWindowViewModel.cs#L24). However, I cannot get the desired outcome. Is it because the module hasn't been initialized?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

did you add your module to the modulecatalog using override method ConfigureModuleCatalog? take a look at [here](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism-Samples-Wpf/blob/master/17-BasicRegionNavigation/BasicRegionNavigation/App.xaml.cs)

Comment: thanks for pointing it out. I did configured as what you show in the link, however, I'm facing problem in how to navigate programmatically to a view when the application loads without explicitly triggering it through button. Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Eventually I solve by adding the following code in MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
public partial class MainWindow
{
    IRegionManager _regionManager;
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _regionManager = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<IRegionManager>();
        RegionManager.SetRegionManager(ContentRegion, _regionManager);
        Loaded += MainWindow_Loaded;
    }

    private void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        _regionManager.RequestNavigate("ContentRegion", "ViewA");
    }
}
```

Get idea from: https://github.com/MahApps/MahApps.Metro/issues/1020#issuecomment-44779574

Answer (score 0):

I'm kinda late to the party here, but I also stumbled over the question of how to navigate to a default view during the applications startup.

I found two ways:

## 1. `App` decides the default view

This can be solved in the `CreateShell()`-override in the `App`-Class.

This is my `CreateShell`-Method:

```cs
/// <inheritdoc />
protected override Window CreateShell()
{
    var window = this.Container.Resolve<MainWindow>();

    window.Loaded += (sender, args) =>
    {
        var manager = this.Container.Resolve<IRegionManager>();

        manager.RequestNavigate("ContentRegion", "ViewA");
    };

    return window;
}
```

## 2. ViewModel decides the default view

Add a constructor to `MainWindowViewModel` that looks like this:

```cs
public MainWindowViewModel(IRegionManager regionManager)
{
    regionManager.RegisterViewWithRegion("ContentRegion", "ViewA");
}
```